# Can not stop web-server since updating to the latest OS version

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, raspbian

I broke down my program to simple 60 liner, which should start and stop a Tornado server after 2 secs. This piece of code worked with an earlier Debian version but it hangs and does not stop with the current one:

```
> uname -a
Linux xyz 4.14.79-v7+ #1159 SMP Sun Nov 4 17:50:20 GMT 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

import time
import threading
import logging
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.websocket

class HTTPHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    """HTTP request handler for my simplyfied web-server."""

    def initialize(self):
        pass

    def get(self):
        """Execute HTTP GET commands."""
        self.set_status(200)
        self.set_header('Content-type', "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        self.write("HI")

class WebServer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        """Setup web-server on a configured port."""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.port = 4030

    def run(self):
        """Start listening on port as a web-server."""
        application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/.*", HTTPHandler)])
        httpd = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        interface, ip = ("eth0", "192.168.2.4")
        httpd.listen(self.port, address=ip)
        logging.info("WebServer Starts - %s(%s):%s", ip, interface, self.port)
        log = logging.getLogger("tornado.access")
        log.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

        logging.info("WebServer exiting")

    def stop(self):
        """Set shutdown flag for the thread to stop."""
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
    rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.getLogger("tornado.general").setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    logging.getLogger("tornado.application").setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
    logging.getLogger("tornado.access").setLevel(logging.NOTSET)

    ws = WebServer()
    ws.start()

    time.sleep(2.0)
    logging.debug("Stopping")
    ws.stop()
```

To be honest I can not recall what was the previous OS version, but it was an at-least one year old version. Any idea what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `IOLoop.instance().stop()` from the main thread, which is not allowed. The *only* method in Tornado that is safe to call from a thread other than the one where the IOLoop is running is `IOLoop.add_callback`. To initiate a shutdown from the main thread while the IOLoop is running on another thread, replace your stop method with this:

```
def stop(self):
    """Instruct the IOLoop to stop itself."""
    IOLoop.instance().add_callback(IOLoop.instance().stop)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still hangs. Is there a way I could find where is it "looping" or hanging?

Comment: Send it a SIGINT and see the stack trace printed to stderr?

Comment: No stack-trace comes for SIGINT and the process keeps hanging.

Comment: Well, actually it is not hanging, it is still serving requests. Even after the stop I can issue HTTP GETs and get a response.

Comment: I'm still stuck at the same point. Any idea? Do you have any chance  to test it on a Raspbian Stretch? It works on e.g. Fedora 23.